# Determine time and length of last suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, time

I would like to know time and length of last system suspend. Is it possible?

**EDIT**

```
dmesg | grep -A10 suspend
[27075.428135] PM: suspend of devices complete after 998.769 msecs
[27075.432139] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 4.000 msecs
[27075.432325] r8169 0000:02:00.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[27075.448098] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[27075.452115] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[27075.460035] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup enabled by ACPI
[27075.464397] PM: noirq suspend of devices complete after 32.255 msecs
[27075.464646] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[27075.464873] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[27075.465405] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[27075.466662] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU1
[27075.568014] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[27075.569471] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU2
[27075.672016] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[27075.673417] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU3
[27075.776020] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[27075.777422] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU4
[27075.880019] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
[27075.881376] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU5
[27075.984012] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[27075.984393] Broke affinity for irq 23
[27075.985396] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU6
[27076.088010] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
[27076.089372] kvm: disabling virtualization on CPU7
[27076.192012] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[27076.192213] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[27076.192213] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
```

Comment: You could try looking at what is logged in `dmesg`...

Comment: `dmesg` is indeed good advice:)

Comment: Did you get this `dmesg` output after suspending and quickly resuming? (More than 10 lines may be helpful as well)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at these lines:

```
[27075.428135] PM: suspend of devices complete after 998.769 msecs
[27075.432139] PM: late suspend of devices complete after 4.000 msecs
...
...
[27076.192213] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
```

These, at a guess show when it start and finished suspending. So a way to get the time when it started suspending is:

```
dmesg | egrep -i "suspend|complete" | head -1 | cut -d ] -f1 | tr -d [
```

and when it finished

```
dmesg | egrep -i "resume complete" | head -1 | cut -d ] -f1 | tr -d [
```

So a way to get a guess at the time between when it suspended and resumed is:

```
expr "$(dmesg | egrep -i "resume complete" | head -1 | cut -d ] -f1 | tr -d [ | cut -d . -f1)" - "$(dmesg | egrep -i "suspend|complete" | head -1 | cut -d ] -f1 | tr -d [ | cut -d . -f1)"
```

There are likely much better ways to do this....

*(N.B. using `dmesg -T` to show the time might not work - following this entry in `man dmesg`:*

> -T, --ctime
>    Print human readable timestamps. The timestamp could be inaccurate!
>    **The time source used for the logs is not  updated  after  system SUSPEND/RESUME.**

*)*